# JPEG HW Decoder access API

Tags: android, jpeg, decoder

Is there any procedure/API provided in Android SDK/NDK to check if "JPEG HW Decoder" exists in the underlying android phone handset?

If yes, then

Is there any procedure/API provided in Android SDK/NDK to access "JPEG HW Decoder" for decompressing JPEG image?

( I guess PV Media framework provides access for the same, but I am not sure)

I plan to use JPEG hardware decoder to decompress jpeg image for achieving peformance. Please comment!

Thanks,
Rodney

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the NDK and libjpeg-turbo to make use of neon instructions where available.